# Issue when I click a button in Virtual Device

Tags: android-activity

I'm trying to create a app with 3 pages of information.

My ultimate aim is, to create 3 buttons and when the button is clicked the relative layout for that activity should be opened.

I created the 3 activity in manifest.xml and 3 different layouts and 3 java classes and coding is all done.

Now When i click any button in the Virtual device, i get "Unfortunately Page has stopped ".

Below is the LogCat file:

> 03-22 03:45:40.971: D/dalvikvm(1158): GC_CONCURRENT freed 285K, 15%
>   free 2581K/3012K, paused 37ms+13ms, total 237ms
>
> 03-22 03:45:40.971: D/dalvikvm(1158): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked
>   101ms
>
> 03-22 03:45:41.191: I/Choreographer(1158): Skipped 67 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 03-22 03:45:41.672: I/Choreographer(1158): Skipped 161 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 03-22 03:45:41.861: D/gralloc_goldfish(1158): Emulator without GPU
>   emulation detected.
>
> 03-22 03:46:05.892: D/AndroidRuntime(1158): Shutting down VM
>
> 03-22 03:46:05.892: W/dalvikvm(1158): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): ... 11 more
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.page/com.example.page.Page3}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): at
>   com.example.page.PageActivity.onClickPage3(PageActivity.java:32)
>
> 03-22 03:46:06.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): ... 14 more
>
> 03-22 03:51:06.541: I/Process(1158): Sending signal. PID: 1158 SIG: 9

Comment: LogCat is showing ActivityNotFound exception. Probably you did not declare the activities in the manifest.